# Inject EJB in @serverEndpoint class results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, weld

I'm using Swarm Wildfly to deploy this application.
Basically I'm making a websocket enabled application.

I'd like to inject a singleton which will be started on the startup which modify the variable result.

Upon accessing the "/rafflethis" link, user will be able to see the result which will be sent via session.

The result is that the `roll` variable **null**

This is the class

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class runMe implements RaffleManager{
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(runMe.class.getName());

  private static String result;

  @PostConstruct
  public void onStartup() {
    System.out.println("Initialization success.");
  }

  @Schedule(second = "*/10", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
  public void run() throws Exception{
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
      Thread.sleep(1000L);
      result = UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase();
      i++;
      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "i : " + i);
    }
  }

  public String getResult() {
    return result;
  }
}
```

interface

```
public interface RaffleManager {
  String getResult();
}
```

And the "/rafflethis"

```
@ServerEndpoint("/rafflethis")
public class RaffleThis implements Serializable {
  @EJB
  RaffleManager roll;

  private static final Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

  private static void sendMessageToAll(String message) {
    for (Session s : sessions) {
      try {
        s.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  @OnOpen
  public void monitorLuckyDip(Session session) throws Exception {
    sessions.add(session);
    while(true) {
      sendMessageToAll(roll.getResult());
    }
  }
}
```

Any lead where should I head from this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is rather hacky but a very simple one indeed. Take a look at the provided diagram.

[image: Logic]

And here's the code

Logic Implementation:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class RunMe{
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RunMe.class.getName());


  @Inject
  MessageDTO messageDTO;


  @PostConstruct
  public void onStartup() {
    System.out.println("Initialization success.");
  }

  @Schedule(second = "*/10", minute = "*", hour = "*", persistent = false)
  public void run() throws Exception{
    //You can also substitute this method with constructor of the class -- removing the @Schedule annotation.
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
      Thread.sleep(1000L);
      messageDTO.setText(UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase());
      i++;
      LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "i : " + i);
    }
  }
}
```

MessageDTO:

```
@Singleton
public class MessageDTO {
  private static String text;

  public static String getText() {
    return text;
  }

  public static void setText(String text) {
    MessageDTO.text = text;
  }
}
```

Websocket Implementation:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/rafflethis")
public class RaffleThis implements Serializable {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(RaffleThis.class.getName());
  private static final Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());
  @Inject
  MessageDTO messageDTO;

  private static void sendMessageToAll(String message) {
    for (Session s : sessions) {
      try {
        s.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  @OnOpen
  public void monitorLuckyDip(Session session) throws Exception {
    sessions.add(session);
    while (true) {
      Thread.sleep(200);
      sendMessageToAll(messageDTO.getText());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source, I would probably assume a name issue.
Your singleton bean "runMe" is the actual name of the bean not the interface.

SIDE NOTE: Best practice for class names is capitalize the first letter. RunMe instead of runMe.

@Singleton - without parameters will automatically name your bean for lookup using the bean convention from your class name. Imagine if you implement multiple interface, how does EJB pick the name? So it is just logical to use the class name. E.g. If your classname is TestMe, the ejb name will be testMe.

In your case since your class name is runMe, I would think the bean name will be runMe.

To ensure the lookup will not fail, you can specific the name in @Singleton and @EJB.

```
@Singleton(name = "runMe")
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class runMe implements RaffleManager{
```

Then in your Service end point class

```
@ServerEndpoint("/rafflethis")
public class RaffleThis implements Serializable {
    @EJB(beanName ="runMe")
    RaffleManager roll;
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of the runMe class, I'm just too lazy to rename it.

Thanks for the answer. I'll see in the future that the problem can be solved with this method. I've found the  solution which I'll be answering in below.. Thanks for your help and answer!